# Idle Hands - A study on clocks

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

(Author Note) A while ago I made some puzzles for a now defunct puzzle hunt project, here's one of them. The answer to this ([and most other puzzles of said hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22A+study+on%22+is%3Aquestion)) is a single word. The puzzle itself is fully contained within the image above. Author notes don't matter.

Hint:

> What time is it?

Hint 2:

> How could you obtain letters from hours?

Hint 3:

> Those numbers are too regular soldier, switch them to the proper format!

Hint 4:

> The clock isn't rightside up.

Comment: what kind of answer do u expect?

Comment: The answer is a word, be sure to check the tags if you're unsure

Comment: Which one is the hour hand?

Comment: That's yours to figure out !

Comment: rot13(Vf gur pybpx gur evtug fvqr hc? V nfx, orpnhfr guvf cnegvphyne neenatrzrag bs unaqf frrzf vzcbffvoyr vs vg vf? ng rvtug zvahgrf cnfg guerr, gur ubhe unaq jbhyq abg or fznpx ba gur guerr naq ng dhnegre cnfg bar, gur ubhe unaq jbhyq or n ybg pybfre gb gur bar.)

Comment: Added a hint for ya

Comment: Very nice puzzle!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> ECLIPSE

It is obtained by

> Beginning with what MetaZen explained, collect all the letters in order traversing counter-clockwise.  The E will be passed twice in this manner.

Comment: That makes sense with the "Let's go back thirteen hours."

Comment: That is indeed correct, feel free to make your answer a tad more complete. You get the mark nonetheless, congrats to you and everyone else who gave a crack at this puzzle !

Comment: Awesome.  I knew I was missing the 13 hours part, but had two of my letters out of order so I didn't see it.  Nice work!

Answer (score 9):

I believe the answer is

> SPLICE

The time is:

> 4:30, because the hour hand is halfway between two points, meaning the minute hand would be on the 6, so that's our orientation.

Given that, the six relevant points are:

> 3, 4+1=5, 7+12=19 (convert for military), 8+12-4=16, 11-2=9, 12

These translate to

> C, E, S, P, I, L

The only word that can be compiled from these that I can find is

> SPLICE

Comment: You are missing a key element to find the true answer, be sure to look at everything in the image!